# Mutable array get overridden when get asserted to another variable

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, pass-by-reference, mutablelist

I have A simple case where I Have "List A" with 5 values and another "List B"  acts As TempList  holding "List A" values
now when I call "list_A.clear()"
"list_B" also get Cleared why?

```
val List_A: MutableList<String> = ArrayList<String>()


List_A.add("index_1")
List_A.add("index_2")
List_A.add("index_3")
List_A.add("index_4")
List_A.add("index_5")

val  List_B = List_A
List_A.clear()
```

## Result

```
List_A-----Size--------> 0
List_B-----Size--------> 0
```

Please Note that it works as expected when I define "List_B" as

```
var List_B: MutableList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
  then
List_B.addAll(List_A)
```

## Result

```
List_A-----Size--------> 0
List_B-----Size--------> 5
```

Does kotlin passes List_A variable  Referance to List_B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an object and assign a reference to that object to **List_A**, a memory is allocated for that object and it has some address, say **@eae072e**. **List_A** is a reference to that object. When you create a variable **List_B** and assign to it **List_A**, they both refer to the same address in memory **@eae072e**. So when you use one of them to manipulate with data, this manipulation will be reflected in both of them - in **List_A** and **List_B**.

To avoid it new instance of **List_B** should be created:

```
var List_B: MutableList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
List_B.addAll(List_A)
```

And then you can clear the list **List_A** and it not be reflected in **List_B**:

```
List_A.clear() 
// List_A is empty, List_B will contain items
```

Comment: According to your answer if i understand can "stack memory" have same address twice
thank you...

Comment: Two variables can refer to the same address in memory.

Answer (score 2):

> Does kotlin passes List_A variable Referance to List_B ?

Exactly. Both `List_A` and `List_B` refer to the same address in memory. If you want to make a copy you need to create a new `ArrayList` and add all elements into it with `addAll`. After that you may clear `List_A`.

**Example**

```
val listA: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("index_0", "index_1", "index_2")
val listB: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
listB.addAll(listA)
listA.clear()
```

Although it'll work fine with `String` in your case, you must understand that new list contains same objects (reference to the same objects), not a copy of them. So if you don't clear `listA` and change an element of it, that element will also be changed in `listB` accordingly.

Comment: dosen't Kotlin Pass variable By value Like Java  as it using same JVM
and why declarign List_B not creating new Adress in memory
thank you for your response ..

Answer (score 2):

`listA` and `listB` both hold the same reference the time you call `clear()`.

What you need to do is to make a copy of `listA` by calling `toMutableList()`.

```
val listA = ArrayList<String>()

listA.add("index_1")
listA.add("index_2")
// ...

val listB = listA.toMutableList()
listA.clear()
// listB will be unchangend
```

**Note:**

- You should stick to Kotlin's naming conventions, so your variables should be in camel-case without underscore.
- The type of `listA` can be inferred, so there is no need to specifiy the type explicitely.